# Primefaces FileUpload - Simple bootstrap styling?

Tags: css, file-upload, primefaces, styling

I have implemented the file upload controller on my *.xhtml +  PF 3.5 Page:

```
        <div class="control-group">
        <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <p:messages showDetail="true" />

            <p:fileUpload value="#{fileUploadController.file}" mode="simple" />

            <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false"
                actionListener="#{fileUploadController.upload}" />

        </h:form>
    </div>
```

I do not use any styles on the uploader, however, at the moment it looks like that:

[image]

I want to let it look like on the PF Page:

[File Uploader](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadSimple.jsf)

What do I have to change? I really appreciate your answer!!!

Comment: Display in Chrome is different from firefox, so what do you mean 'like PF' page ?

Comment: Thx for your answer! I mean like on the PF Page(link: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadSimple.jsf), when you change your THEME to Bootstrap.

Comment: @maximus changing theme to Bootstrap is not changing how `<p:fileUpload mode="simple"/>` looks. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ÖmerFarukAlmalı yep thats right!

Comment: @maximus so you should follow my answer to customize file upload button :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do not recommend to use `<p:fileUpload mode="simple"/>` if you want to customize the filupload button. Giving css properties like `background-color` or others will occur weird look&feel.

Instead of it, you can use  `<p:fileUpload mode="advance"/>` and modify anything of it, `.ui-fileupload .fileinput-button` class provides to change button's css, `.fileupload-content` makes easy to manipulate content's css. For example:

```
.fileupload-buttonbar {
    background: transparent none;
    border: none;
}

.fileupload-content {
    display: none;
}

.ui-fileupload .fileinput-button {
    background-color: rgba(142, 103, 64, 0.98);
}
```

Generates such a file upload button:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Ömer Faruk Almalı's answer updated for **primefaces 5** for fellow googlers who find this thread:

```
.ui-fileupload-buttonbar {
    background: transparent none;
    border: none;
}

.ui-fileupload-content {
    display: none;
}

.ui-fileupload-buttonbar .ui-fileupload-choose {
    background-color: rgba(142, 103, 64, 0.98);
}
```